# Android - Can you have multiple apps publishing the same intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, ipc

I need to implement an android broadcast style IPC - not dissimilar in concept to UDP or a message bus.

Several android apps need to be able to broadcast messages "MessageTypeX" to listening android apps.

Thus there may be 1 or more applications that can generate messages of "MessageTypeX" and one or more applications interested in hearing about every "MessageTypeX" message. These consumers will all do their own things with the received message.

Can this be done - I'm anticipating it should be done using intents but I'm not quite sure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

Yes, you can register multiple BroadcastReceivers to the same intent. And ofcourse send them same.